# How to show/hide flash object using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I want to embed this timer in a website. Basically I generated a timer from this [website](http://www.oneplusyou.com/bb/countdown). Then I would use this code and inject it to an html page. The code works great, however I only want to use this timer for some specific case (ie, using if-else) as followed:

```
<script> 

flash = '<object type=&quot;application/x-shockwave-flash&quot; data=&quot;http://www.oneplusyou.com/bb/files/countdown/countdown.swf?co=000000&bgcolor=ffffff&date_month=10&date_day=26&date_year=0&un=DEAL ENDS&size=normal&mo=10&da=26&yr=2014&quot; width=&quot;250&quot; height=&quot;100&quot;><param name=&quot;movie&quot; value=&quot;http://www.oneplusyou.com/bb/files/countdown/countdown.swf?co=000000&bgcolor=ffffff&date_month=10&date_day=26&date_year=0&un=DEAL ENDS&size=normal&mo=10&da=26&yr=2014&quot; /><param name=&quot;bgcolor&quot; value=&quot;#ffffff&quot; /></object>';`

    if (new Date().getHours() < 20) {
        document.write(flash);
    }

</script>
```

But then I'll get this error `no plugin available to display this content`

So how would I built something like this another way, or maybe there's a fix for this

THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll propose 2 options and I'm sure there is bunch more out there. First one should work with your flash option....

**OPTION 1**
First put your flash object on the page with style `display:none`. Then in your javascript you evaluate if it's time to show it.

HTML EXAMPLE 1:

```
<object id="myCountdown" style="display:none;" width="400" height="50" data="path-to-your-flash.swf"></object>
```

HTML EXAMPLE 2 with classes and css - prefered:

```
<object id="myCountdown" class="hidden" width="400" height="50" data="path-to-your-flash.swf"></object>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden{display:none;}
```

JS:

```
if(new Date().getHours() < 20){
   $('#myCountdown').css('display', 'block'); //using jQuery for first example

//OR

   $('#myCountdown').removeClass('hidden'); //using jQuery exmaple 2
}
```

**OPTION 2:**

Talking about building it another way I would use a plugin: [COUNTDOWN.JS](http://countdownjs.org/)

Comment: Thanks, it works, but say I have 4 products on my page, but using either of these methods, only one product show the countdown, the other ones don't, any suggestion?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to show countdown for each product, right? In that case if you are using flash objects, you will need 4 flash objects with 4 different ids with different names. And then do `$('#countdown1').removeClass('hidden');`, `$('#countdown2').removeClass('hidden');` etc. when needed. If you will have many more then 4 products, then this will become very quickly unmanageable so you would have to look into more sophisticated solutions (Javascript Object OR databases) and loop through through them. But thats a whole new subject.